# Capacitance of a system of 2 connected spheres

Tags: capacitor, capacitance

[image]

Consider the above set-up of 2 connected conducting spheres. I am required to find the equivalent capacitance of this system. Now, I know both of them will attain an equal potential in steady state and in that state
$$\frac{Q_{a}}{C_{a}} = \frac{Q_{b}}{C_{b}} = \frac{Q_{net}}{C_{a} + C_{b}} = V$$

This would imply that
$$C_{eqv}=C_a+C_b$$
This means that the system is in a parallel combination.

However, if I assume the two spheres to be sphere capacitors with the opposite sphere at infinity, I am unable to visualise how this system is a parallel combination of capacitors. What is the intuition behind this system being in a parallel combination? How exactly can we draw its simplified circuit diagram without knowing the calculations beforehand?